Very slow delivery via AWS Event Bridge
I have previously tested AWS Event Bridge and it seemed very fast to me. However, in a new project where I am uploading data at a high rate via Ruby, it is falling orders of magnitude short of expectations. The data goes straight from EventBridge to SQS and I can confirm it is not an SQS issue.When uploading the data to Event Bridge, it appears on SQS at a rate of a few thousand messages a minute.
I was expecting at least thousands of messages a second. In my previous testing it seemed much, much faster. I have searched high and low but I cannot understand what could slow it down so much. Checking quotas in the panel I should be able to hit 10 000 put operations a second. The put Events from the client themselves are not limited, only the delivery from Event Bridge to the SQS queue which should be seamless.

Have you compared the SQS metrics to the EventBridge metrics?

Today I learned that you could put your own EventBridge events, by the way. What is the use case instead of sending the events directly to SQS?

@DMalan the main use case was to take advantage of EventBridge's replay ability. Sending direct to SQS is way, way faster.
